# data lost in segue (xcode8.0)

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, segue

I am a beginner in swift and try to develop simple program which shows characterisitcs of BLE. I confirmed by print that I captured UUID of target characteristics

```
myCharacteristicUUID_1 : (
    "Manufacturer Name String",
    "Model Number String",
    "Serial Number String",
    "Hardware Revision String",
    "Firmware Revision String",
    "Software Revision String"
)
```

However, in override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?),
I checked it again by print and I see the data is gone as below;

```
myCharacteristicUUID_2 : (
)
```

I can hand over other types of values (e.g.string, text,etc..) but I can't handle the data captured from BLE. Can somebody point out what I have to do when I use the data from BLE in the segue ?
Below is my code;

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor targetService: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if error != nil {
        print("Characteristic NOT found : \(error)")

    }

    let foundCharacteristics = targetService.characteristics

    for c in foundCharacteristics! as [CBCharacteristic] {

        myCharacteristicUUID.add(c.uuid)

    }

    print("myCharacteristicUUID_1 : \(myCharacteristicUUID)")

}

// prepare for segue
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {

        print("myCharacteristicUUID_2 : \(myCharacteristicUUID)")

        let mySecondViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

        mySecondViewController.relayedFoundCharacteristicUUID = myCharacteristicUUID

     }

}
```

Comment: What is `myCharacteristicUUID` type? Look to me like is not being persisted when the function is completed.

Comment: I set myCharacteristicUUID as NSMutableArray.  I started learning swift just a few weeks ago and still struggling...

Comment: Can you show how you declare the `myCharacteristicUUID` in code?

Comment: I found the reason. I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason why `myCharacterisitcUUID` was not read correctly. Please see the place of `performSegue`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedService = myService[indexPath.row] as! CBService
    print("Selected_service : \(selectedService)")

    self.peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for:selectedService as CBService!)

    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: nil)
    // I used to performed segue here. This was the reason myCharacterisitcUUID was empty.


}

// find the characteristics for the targetService

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor targetService: CBService, error: Error?) {

    if error != nil {
        print("Characteristic NOT found : \(error)")

    }

    foundCharacteristics = targetService.characteristics!

    for c in foundCharacteristics as [CBCharacteristic] {

        self.myCharacteristicUUID.add(c.uuid)

    }
    // segue should be performed here ! This change worked!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: nil)
}
```